# Horizontal scrolling in a column layout panel

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am troubled with this issue of horizontal scrollbar not apprearing in my Panel. My application is put up as 6 panels in column layout. Each panel is 250px in width. The issue is  that the 6th panel gets displayed under the 5th panel rather than on its side!!

How do I display the last panel on the right side rather than under the 5th? Here is my code snippet:

```
var appPanel = new Ext.Panel({
    applyTo: document.body,
    autoWidth: true,
    autoScroll: true,
    title: 'Users & Groups Panel',
    layout:'column',
    items: [{
        items: p1
    },{
        items: p2
    },{
        items: p3
    },{
        items: p4
    },{
        items: p5
    },{
        items: p6
    }]
});
```

Each panel is declared with a width of 250px as given below:

```
var p1= new Ext.Panel({
    frame:false,
    width:250,      
    collapsible:false,
    title:'Prime Users',
    items: ...
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ColumnLayout` is defined as having floated columns, so they'll always wrap if you define fixed widths that exceed the overall container width.  You should either use percentage widths instead or use a different layout style (or override the layout's default CSS to do what you need).